# PHP mb_convert_encoding doesn't work on query

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, mb-convert-encoding

I am trying to generate a query string. Characters show up as different queries.

Php version:7.3.2

Function

```
$D->query = '';

if ($this->query('x')) {

    $D->query = mb_convert_encoding($this->query('x'), 'UTF-8');
}
```

Result for #Синодал:

```
#%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB
```

Comment: Show us the text you are starting with.  "Query string" is ambiguous; please elaborate.  Normally, you should never need `mb_convert*`

Answer (score 1):

The string is [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)d, you need to simply [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) first, from there you can do any encoding changes:

```
$decoded = urldecode($this->query(“x”));
$D->query = mb_convert_encoding($decoded, “utf-8”);
```